# What does the 'iv' in glGetShaderiv() stand for?

Tags: opengl

What does the `iv` at the end of `glGetShaderiv()` stand for?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It describes the parameters returned, in this case a **vector** of **ints**. The same nomenclature is used for `glTexParameteriv` and `glTexParameterfv` for example, which updates a vector of ints or floats respectively.

Answer (score 12):

`OpenGL` has some organized naming conventions regarding the routines they have in the libraries.

**Prefixes**

All routines have a `gl` before them. Similar thing you must have observed with `glu` and `glut`. Some vender libraries also have prefixes like `NVidia` guys have put up a `NV_` prefix in the hardware feature flags.

**Suffixes**

Suffixes usually are an indicator to what kind of arguments does the method take.

- Some specifying the context of the function. e.g. `1D`, `2D` or `3D`
  e.g. `glTexCoord2D`
- Kind of value types is a function's argument taking. e.g. `glTranslatef` takes `GLfloat` arguments (observe that even the data types follow the same naming convention) and `glTranslated` take `GLdouble`.
- The source of the vertices (usually when there are too many vertices and you store them in a single array) taking the method you have mentioned:
  `glGetShaderiv` is a function, takes the parameters for `shaders`, where datatype is `GLint` and the source of data is a `vector` (`v`).

You can take such kind of conventions to easily identify that what method takes what kind of arguments.

Answer (score 4):

It indicates you want to get a value that is an array of integers. The function reference can be found [here](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetShaderiv.xml), and as you can see, the return param is a `GLint *`. This is in contrast to functions such as `glGetInternalFormati64v`, which has a return param of `GLint64 *`. I believe, but can't locate at the moment, that there have been functions using the `fv` suffix to denote floats, and possibly others.